# Can one start shell from save file dialog

Tags: ubuntu, bash, terminal, shell

Using ubuntu. If one tries to print to a file, the save dialog opens. Is there a way one can execute the shell (or terminal) from the save file dialog file name entry box?

Comment: AFAIK No, unless you find some undiscovered hack.

Comment: This sounds similar to [old hack](http://imgur.com/gallery/fqjnK) to login to Windows without password. But I guess that it's impossible.